# How do I fix this method for creating a tuple with only unique values, where the data is coming in through a for loop from a grouped 2D dataframe?

Tags: python, tuples, conditional-statements

I'm trying to extract a column from a 2D dataframe and manipulate it so that it is a tuple and has no repeated values.

My solution to create the tuple worked fine, create a tuple *(temp_tuple)* that will hold the value coming in and append it to a tuple *(xax_country)*.

I now want to check *(temp_tuple)* before adding it to *(xax_country)*, to make sure it does not match any of the values already in *(xax_country)*.

```python
#read the data from csv file using pandas.
salary = pd.read_csv('EuropeanDevelopers.csv') 
salary.columns = ['Experience', 'Salary', 'Gender', 'Country']
salary.head()

xax_country=()
salary = salary.groupby(['Country', 'Gender'])

for a, a_salary in salary: 

    #need to find a way to add the country only if it has not been added 

    if not(any(a[0] in i for i in xax_country)
        temptuple = (a[0],)#syntax error happens here
    else
        temptuple = (0,)

    if temptuple != 0    
        xax_country +=temptuple
```

However I get a syntax error for the same exact thing that worked before adding the if statements in.

The ultimate goal is to take this data, as well as well as the means of salaries by gender for each country, and get them on a bar graph.

Answer (score 0):

I just discarded the whole loop mess and did this.

```py
xax_country=salary
xax_country = salary.sort_values(['Country'])
xax_country = xax_country.drop_duplicates(['Country'])
xax_country = tuple(list(xax_country['Country']))
```

Which made xax_country into a tuple with just the countries in order.

Did not even know about drop_duplicates, what a great tool.